# Why does playing mp3s force crash?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I used the same exact code but with .wav files and it worked-- for about 50 plays and then it crashed. I switched over to mp3 files and they won't play at all.

The program itself works fine-- I know the error occurs in this case below:

```
case R.id.playButton: 
        switch (korean.getIndex()){
        case -1: break; // This is the case when the program first starts.
        case 0: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c0).start(); break; 
        case 1: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c1).start(); break; 
        case 2: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c2).start(); break; 
        case 3: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c3).start(); break; 
        case 4: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c4).start(); break; 
        case 5: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c5).start(); break; 
        case 6: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c6).start(); break; 
        case 7: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c7).start(); break; 
        case 8: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c8).start(); break; 
        case 9: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c9).start(); break; 
        case 10: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c10).start(); break; 
        case 11: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c11).start(); break; 
        case 12: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c12).start(); break; 
        case 13: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c13).start(); break; 
        case 14: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v14).start(); break; 
        case 15: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v15).start(); break; 
        case 16: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v16).start(); break; 
        case 17: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v17).start(); break; 
        case 18: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v18).start(); break; 
        case 19: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v19).start(); break; 
        case 20: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v20).start(); break; 
        case 21: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v21).start(); break; 
        case 22: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v22).start(); break; 
        case 23: MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.v23).start(); break; 
        default: break;
        }
```

I know that's a lot-- but those are static method calls, so it should be alright, right? Why would this crash?

Comment: Funny, you think Google would know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create MediaPlayer objects one after another and never release the resources, so you are probably running out of memory, consider:

```
// declare mp as class field.
MediaPlayer mp = null;

//...

case R.id.playButton:
    if (mp != null)
        mp.release();
    switch (korean.getIndex()){
    case -1: break; // This is the case when the program first starts.
    case 0: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c0);mp.start(); break; 
    case 1: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c1);mp.start(); break; 
    case 2: mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.c2);mp.start(); break; 
    // and so on
```

Alternatively, you can [set OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) and call `release` there.

Comment: Are you sure `mp` is declared as a class field and not in a method? also, consider the second option I added now.

Comment: Sorry-- I learned the problem is somehow with the encoding of the mp3. This solution works perfectly for wav files but for some reason mp3s are not working. edit: I declared mp as a private class member (same class the listener is in).